# Recharts : trying to display data from FIREBASE in bar chart

Tags: reactjs, json, recharts

I can't remove timestamp cuz i need to update new data
so i use reactJS and this is what i am tring to do
i'm import that json file sampledata and using it in barchar tag, but for some reason i could not get output

```
import sampledata from './ramdata.json';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <BarChart width={730} height={250} data={sampledata}>
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <XAxis />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip />
    <Legend />
    <Bar dataKey="active_memory" fill="#8884d8" />
    <Bar dataKey="available_memory" fill="#82ca9d" />
  </BarChart>         
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is JSON file(ramdata.json):

```
[{
  "1686205520": {
    "active_memory": 6812368896,
    "available_memory": 7099367424,
    "percent_of_ram_used": 58.7,
    "total_memory": 17179869184,
    "wired_memory": 1781694464
  },
  "1686205527": {
    "active_memory": 6782124032,
    "available_memory": 7116718080,
    "percent_of_ram_used": 58.6,
    "total_memory": 17179869184,
    "wired_memory": 1794670592
  },
  "1686205529": {
    "active_memory": 6866092032,
    "available_memory": 7062929408,
    "percent_of_ram_used": 58.9,
    "total_memory": 17179869184,
    "wired_memory": 1765605376
  }
}]
```

Comment: I just figured it out, instead of using timestamps is used number from 0...n, just like index